# Basic webapp integrating jersey+Spring+hibernate

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, tomcat, jersey

Similar questions in the forum are unanswered, since being noob with Restful Web services i had to raise this question.

A mavenized dynamic Web application to fetch data from database in a JASON format.

- Database: apache derby 1.1
- Eclipse: Juno
- JDK: 1.8
- Spring: 4.2.3
- Hibernate: 5.0
- Jersey: 2.19
- Apache tomcat v8.0
- Design patterns used: none as its a very basic integration

### Design

1. Model class mimics the table from the database (Spring bean) & JSon model.
2. DaoImpl class--> a spring bean with dependency satisfied using spring support classes for hibernate.
3. contextWrapper class -->registered using @Provider used to invoke spring context and fetch results from DaoImpl class
4. RestService class--> handle rest resource request fetch results from contextWrapper class

Compiles and deploys well without errors in server logs however NullpointerException is being thrown from jersey when resource is accessed.
as per logs Spring context has no issues loading.

### Tomcat console logs

```
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JerseySpringHibernate' did not find a matching property.
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.24.0
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_51-b16
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\integration\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.24
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\integration\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.24
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\integration\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\endorsed
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\db-derby\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2222 ms
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Dec 01, 2015 12:11:57 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [248] milliseconds.
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:16 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:17 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:17 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 01 00:12:17 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:18 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring.xml]
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:19 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:21 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.4.Final}
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:21 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:25 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:32 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 14945 ms
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 01, 2015 12:12:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 40066 ms
Dec 01, 2015 12:14:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/JerseySpringHibernate] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.shekar.service.RestRequestService.allRows(RestRequestService.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>JerseySpringHibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>JerseySpringHibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.19</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



<dependencies>
<!-- Jersey 2.19 configuration -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>


<!-- Persistence Api » 1.0.2 -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- jersey dependency APIs for CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection for Java) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-EDR1</version>
</dependency>

<!--Ejb Api » 3.0 -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- spring configuration -->

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring JDBC -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!--JSR250 annotation -->

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency> 


<!-- Spring orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!--java transaction API JTA configuration -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- hibernate configuration -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Derby dirver config for maven -->


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>



  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>JerseySpringHibernate</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.shekar</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- loading spring context -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 



</web-app>
```

### Spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="circle" class="org.shekar.model.CircleModel" scope="prototype"/>

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" autowire="constructor"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test;create=true"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="sessn" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.shekar.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="DaoImpl" class="org.shekar.dao.DaoImpl">
    <property name="sessn" ref="sessn"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

PS: -Any Design mistakes be forgiven I am noob, this post is solely for learning purpose

Comment: Pointing me to right direction will also do

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. But I have to correct you. Stackoverflow is not a _forum_. It is Q/A (questions and answer) site. So you try to improve your question until it is a perfect one. Saying to be a "noob" won't protect you from reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: @TobiasLiefke thanks I am not new to stack overflow but Restful webservices using jersey ofcourse I am.

Comment: In that case you should read the provided link nevertheless. I can't see any question in your post...

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Question here is Why is Jersey (framework) breaking with NPE ? or Is there a suggestion where I could workaround this

Comment: Please read [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). According to your log the NPE is thrown inside your class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RESTeasy framework instead of Jersey framework for RESTFUL fixed NPE issue apparently Jersey has issues with Spring 4 and Hibernate 5